# Can 1D SPT phase host non-Abelian topological defects?

Tags: topological-order, topological-phase

People usually consider Kitaev chain as a topologically ordered phase in 1D, and the edge modes of Kitaev chain are Majorana zero modes (MZM), which are topological defects with non-Abelian mutual statistics (in quasi-1D network setup). In general, for spin or bosonic systems in 1D, there is no topological order but only symmetry protected topological (SPT) order. Some of 1D SPT phases also have edge modes, e.g. AKLT chain. Can 1D SPT phase host non-Abelian topological defects at the edges? Or is there any generic way of determine mutual statistics of edge modes without composing a network (e.g. [Alicea, et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4395))?

I agree that there is no anyonic excitation in SPT phase, but the edges of 1D SPT are not excitations but domain walls (topological defects). Is there any theory on the statistics of topological defects in SPT?

Comment: This should not be possible, the idea being that if I have a chain whose edges are non-abelian with respect to one another, then there is a non-commutative property between the two edges, which cannot be destroyed by *any* local perturbation (unlike an SPT).

Comment: The only loophole is that one may have *several* non-abelian anyons on one edge (in such a way that a single edge as a whole is in the identity sector). This is for example the case if one stacks two Kitaev chains on top of one another.

Comment: How about Majorana zero mode in Kitaev chain? They apparently have non-Abelian statistics, while can be destroyed by adding local perturbation that breaks fermionic parity symmetry, i.e. quasiparticle poisoning.

Comment: Stability of topological order in *open* systems is a subtle business that I know too little about. But yes my statement was regarding isolated systems.

Comment: Pardon me if I understand it wrongly. I didn't see the difference between a local perturbation like $S^z_1$ in a spin system and $c^{\dagger}_i$ in a fermionic system. The former one could break time-reversal symmetry in a Heisenberg chain and the later one could break fermionic parity symmetry in Kitaev chain.

Comment: In the fermionic case, such a term would violate locality. Indeed by locality one would require $\langle c_i^\dagger c_j \rangle \to \langle c_i^\dagger \rangle \langle c_j \rangle$ (if $|i-j| \to \infty$), however the left-hand side is antisymmetric and the right-hand side symmetric. So locality requires  $ \langle c_i^\dagger \rangle = 0$. This is guaranteed by fermionic parity symmetry, and would be generically violated without it.

Comment: I agree with you that $c^{\dagger}$ term will break parity symmetry. And yet this kind of perturbation is possible in experiments. That is not my main question anymore.. I'm wondering if you could provide me some references on why non-commutative property of the edge modes cannot be destroyed by any local perturbation. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not just saying that such a term breaks P, that is obvious. What I am arguing is that one cannot generate such a term in an isolated system. Do you have indication otherwise?

Comment: No, but I'm a bit confused whether you infer that Kitaev chain would only have non-Abelian statistics in isolated system rather than open system (since there exists $c^{\dagger}$ term that can break parity symmetry). And I'd like to know more on the relation between non-commutativity of the edge mode operators and its mutual statistics in quasi-1D network. I'd appreciate a lot if you could give me some reference on that proof. Thanks!